# add a tool tip to a PrimeFaces p:schedule event?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there way to add a mouse over tool tip to a p:schedule event?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you mean a primeFaces Growl, or tooltip?
Tooltip is used generally for components that have the TITLE attribute, to show a tooltip on generally mouse over.
You cannot add a tool tip to an event but to likely a component like : a `<p:commandButton` or a `<p:graphicImage` ..etc
for events, you'd better use `<p:growl />.`

Example :

```
<p:growl id="mygrowl" global="true" />

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.MyActionListener}" update="mygrowl" />.
```

Just see if `<p:schedule />`  has an eventlistener attribute.

If you want to make sure :
Add between the

```
<p:tooltip global="true" />
 <p:growl showDetail="false" showSummary="true" id="globalgrowl" life="3000"/>
```

Then

Comment: I have tried to add tooltip to p:schedule but it didn't worked. so is it a limitation of primefaces for schedule component?

Answer (score 4):

Use tooltip attribute. Since Primefaces 6.0 there are available to set to true and each event can load its own description.

`<p:schedule tooltip="true"/>`

You must to add the description to the event, of course.

`e = new DefaultScheduleEvent();`
`e.setDescription("<p:outputText value='" + obj.title + "' />");`